# Wrapping html around value in sql table to make table value a link

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am attempting to wrap html for a hyperlink around the value in an sql table.

See IMAGE

[a busy cat http://carmanmanitoba.ca/mysqlquestion.png](http://carmanmanitoba.ca/mysqlquestion.png)

So for every meta_key that is 'Website' I would like to take the contents of meta_value have a string wrapped around it to make it a link IE

'www.heritagerealty.ca' would become `'<a href="http://www.heritagerealty.ca" target="_blank">www.heritagerealty.ca</a>'`

What query would I enter?  I am very new to PHP and editing databases in such a way.

Comment: Why are you doing this? If you want it to print as a hyperlink then use PHP to do so when outputting the value to the page. Converting all the DB entries to hyperlinks not only uses more space and resources it would then make it difficult to add CSS for instance to the hyperlinks among other attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to enter any query while inserting. Just make it link while you are displaying the results like

```
<?php
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) {
?>
<a href="<?php echo $res['meta_value']?>"><?php echo $res['meta_key']?></a>
<?php

}
?>
```

Comment: while this will work I am equally poor with finding where that code is in my wordpress theme, currently I inserted it into the page template with <?php the_meta(); ?>, if that means anything to you :)

Comment: just put it under the `while loop` search for `have_posts` or the section where in a loop your are displaying your results

Comment: I did find it in the template where it needed to be entered and have figured it out, thank you kindly :)